# Trying to redirect entire folder to website front page

Tags: redirect, directory, subdirectory

Our site used to have a blog at oursite.com/blog

Years later, we're still getting many 404s for pages in the /blog/ folder.

How can I use htaccess to redirect the blog folder and all its contents to the front page of our site, oursite.com ?

I have tried a lot of things based on web research but the closet thing I found redirected things like:

oursite.com/blog/?p=3226

to oursite.com/?p=3226

I don't want it to work that way. All blog files no longer exist, so I just want to redirect ALL files from the blog just to the main front page, i.e. oursite.com so:

oursite.com/blog/?p=3226
or
oursite.com/blog/cool-permalink/
or 
oursite.com/blog/image.jpg
or 
oursite.com/blog/

would ALL simply point to oursite.com

Can you please tell me how to do this? I've spent many hours Googling it unsuccessfully...

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.htaccess` inside the `/blog` directory.

Add this line to `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://oursite.com
```

That will take care of any URL that is requested in `/blog/`

If you want everyone to be redirected if the file doesn't on the whole domain no matter what directory they're in just put the `.htaccess` in your main directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache as your front-end, [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is what you want to use. Something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/blog/.* /cool-permalink/ [R]
```